# Moving large number of files since date

Tags: ssh, time, tar

I've recently moved a large number of files from one server to another with

```
tar -c files_in_dir | ssh user@111.222.33.444 'tar -xvf - -C /new/server/files'
```

Which worked very well. However, I'd like to run it again (due to a mistake) but instead of transferring over 120k files again, I just want ones that were recently added (say in the last three days.)

Is there a way to modify this command or write a new one that will do a similar transfer only for recent files?

Answer (score 0):

The tar on the left side has no knowledge of the original tar file to compare. Thus it cannot know which file are newer than the past files. However, I think the -N tar flag with a manual date argument might work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all this why not just use rsync , rsync will copy only diff to destination from the remote server.